# Php sort array items issue

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all i have array for series season and episode names
Here is my array

```
- The Flash 2.Sezon 11.Bölüm
- The Flash 2.Sezon 1.Bölüm
- The Flash 1.Sezon 20.Bölüm
- The Flash 2.Sezon 3.Bölüm
- The Flash 3.Sezon 3.Bölüm
```

(sezon=>season, bolum=>episode in my language)

I want to sort them first episode to last episode

```
- The Flash 1.Sezon 20.Bölüm
- The Flash 2.Sezon 1.Bölüm
- The Flash 2.Sezon 3.Bölüm
- The Flash 2.Sezon 11.Bölüm
- The Flash 3.Sezon 3.Bölüm
```

I tried asort function but not worked. Most items in correct order but some of them not.Here is my full code:

```
$args=array('post_type'  => 'bolum',
            'posts_per_page' =>-1,
            'orderby'    => 'title',
            'meta_query' => array(array(
                                    'key' => 'bolum_dizi',
                                    'value' => '"' . $post_id . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                 )
            );
$episodes = get_posts($args);
```

And this is how i order and print

```
asort($episodes);
foreach( $episodes as $episode ){
echo $episode->post_title .'\n';}
```

How can i do that ?
Thanks so much.

Comment: what is your code? what have you tried? what is the expected output, what is the actual output? we can help you with problems in your code, but we can't read your mind. oh, and maybe give your input-data in the same format as it is defined in your code.

Comment: I mentioned in my post. I tried asort($episodes);

Comment: just post the relevant code. and not just the name of one function without enough information of HOW it was used.

Comment: Why isn't it working for you and what does your code look like? It is not clear from your current question.

Comment: I have $episodes array for items each item has full text in this format : The Flash 1.Sezon 5.Bölüm In for loop i m printing them for debug and order not correct.

Comment: My question looks messy because i couldn't make list order but i wrote everything that you have asked in my post.

Comment: edit your post. include the code. not a description of what you do, but the actual code. simply copy and paste it... use a php-function to show us how your array is built. for example var_dump($episodes) - just give us something to work with.

Comment: I edited post as you want sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **natural sort** which can be achieved using the [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
'- The Flash 2.Sezon 11.Bölüm',
'- The Flash 2.Sezon 1.Bölüm',
'- The Flash 1.Sezon 20.Bölüm',
'- The Flash 2.Sezon 3.Bölüm',
'- The Flash 3.Sezon 3.Bölüm',
);

natsort($arr);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result would be:

```
array(5) {
  [2]=>
  string(30) "- The Flash 1.Sezon 20.Bölüm"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "- The Flash 2.Sezon 1.Bölüm"
  [3]=>
  string(29) "- The Flash 2.Sezon 3.Bölüm"
  [0]=>
  string(30) "- The Flash 2.Sezon 11.Bölüm"
  [4]=>
  string(29) "- The Flash 3.Sezon 3.Bölüm"
}
```

For an array of objects you must use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strnatcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```
usort($episodes, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a->post_title, $b->post_title);
});
```

Comment: It gave 500 internal server error. Only think i did is replace asort with natsort. I replace again with asort and 500 problem fixed. Why it is not working for me ? Maybe php version?

Comment: what version of PHP do you have?

Comment: As per documentation it should be available for PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7. Check the apache error_log to see what's wrong

Comment: [05-Feb-2016 09:03:22 UTC] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/dizipico/public_html/wp-content/themes/tema/functions.php on line 290
[05-Feb-2016 09:03:25 UTC] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/dizipico/public_html/wp-content/themes/tema/functions.php on line 290

Comment: I saw now that your array contains objects.. let me update the answer

Comment: See my updated answer.. you must use `usort` and `strnatcmp` to reach your target